# How do I change a data type of a single column in dataframe with astype()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of float64 in my DataFrame, which needs to be converted into Int.
I tried the both codes, but the datatype remains unchanged (float64)

```
final_df['Total'] = final_df.Total.astype(int)
final_df['Total'] = final_df['Total'].astype(int)
```

Also, could someone explain the difference between dataframe['col'] and dataframe.col?

Comment: That should work unless it threw an error which you didn't indicate whether it did or not, as to your last question prefer `df['col']` over `df.col` , the latter will lead to unexpected behaviour and is error prone, for instance if you have a column named 'mean' or 'sum' and you called `df.mean` this this would give you the function address of the method `df.mean()`, additionally depending on how you assign values, it will either add a new column or add an attribute but you won't know unless you try to access the newly created column

Comment: It didn't throw any error.

Comment: Then what does `final_df.info()` now show? Also if it didn't throw an error then you need to post raw data and code that allows others to attempt to reproduce this as this is now speculative

Answer (score 3):

i think what you did is correct by try like this:

```
final_df['Total'] = final_df['Total'].astype("int")
```